# Disconnect specific database from pgpool II

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pgpool

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 with [pgpool II](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/index.html) version 3.4.13 on Ubuntu 16.04.3
I want to drop a specific database so I must disconnect the database from pgpool.
How can I do this without disconnecting the whole PostgreSQL instance from pgpool?

I myself use below command:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'dbName'
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

...but after executing, I lose all the database connections in pgpool.

Thanks in advanced for any attention.